# Some HTML data is missing when I am trying to do webscraping using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is my code where I am trying to scrape data from this website https://community.hackernoon.com/u/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}

r=requests.get("https://community.hackernoon.com/u/",headers=headers)
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

When I print soup.prettify(), some HTML code is missing, as when I try to find the name of a writer from the website, in that HTML code, it shows no result found and I think that is why this all list is showing an empty list in the output

```
all=soup.find_all("div",{"id":"ember28"})
all
```

Can somebody help me see what is wrong?

Comment: this seems to be js rendered page use selenium

Comment: This is JS enabled website

Comment: thanks, Pygirl and bigbounty . That was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

url = 'https://community.hackernoon.com/u/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
time.sleep(3)
all_list=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"username"})
username_li = [user.text for user in all_list]
```

---

**all_list:**

```
[<span class="username"><a data-user-card="daria" href="/u/daria">daria</a></span>,
 <span class="username"><a data-user-card="alexcg" href="/u/alexcg">alexcg</a></span>,
 <span class="username"><a data-user-card="daytona500-live-tv" href="/u/daytona500-live-tv">daytona500-live-tv</a></span>,
 <span class="username"><a data-user-card="David" href="/u/David">David</a></span>,
 <span class="username"><a data-user-card="kunalmishra" href="/u/kunalmishra">kunalmishra</a></span>
.
.
.
]
```

---

**username_li:**

```
['daria',
 'alexcg',
 'daytona500-live-tv',
 'David',
 'kunalmishra',
 'Hackern00n457',
 'm15o',
 'mobphone22',
 'KeyReel',
 'msarica',
 'jeffsoo2',
 'bforgan',
 'paulandre',
 'kristinamulford24',
 'hgcontent',
 'anthony1',
 'aydin.sakar',
 'jeevansirela',
 'abhikdeora',
 'ce.roso398',
 'michaeltgately',
 'SweetHeartache',
 'max',
 'jgrossman28',
 'alek.shnayder',
 'derwiki',
 'daniel.h.heyman',
 'jmuller',
 'Vadim',
 'jessekorzan',
 'PitBullCH',
 'mbroudy4',
 'kevin.pang.w',
 'tnichols',
 'arpy',
 'list_startengine',
 'pratik.ropia',
 'davidyang',
 'avantika',
 'magneticmessages',
 'ben',
 'rob',
 'doron',
 'rich.kolasa',
 'jjfleagle',
 'B17Z',
 'eugeniya.korotya',
 'will.howard',
 'colin',
 'daniel.henrique.sc']
```

Comment: `pip install webdriver-manager` to install the required package

Answer (score 0):

Some websites like your example don't load all the data on the first load.

In your example, It loads the website base first and then loads the rest of the info using javascript.
(You can test this by disabling javascript in your browser)

You need to simulate a browser (for example, using selenium) to execute the website javascript and then scrape the data after it's been loaded.

Start here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/